# Hadoop start error on ubuntu with ssh

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, digital-ocean

I'm installed hadoop on ubuntu with ssh but I get an error message when starting hadoop.

following is the error message:

```
hadoop@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01:/home/datawarehouse/hadoop-3.0.0$ sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [voiceid.io]
voiceid.io: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01]
ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-nyc1-01: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

where is the problem ? help me please.

Comment: have you set up password less ssh?

Comment: Add the public keys of edge node to data modes and vice versa in the authorized keys, if you haven’t did that.

Comment: yes I have set up password less ssh but not starting

Comment: Did you only set it up between your machine and that server? Or between all servers within the cluster also? Not only between  yours, but each other